# 25 word monero seed english_old - wallet recovery

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed

years ago, I have created a monero wallet and saved my 25 word seed.
Today, when I try to restore the wallet using mnemonic seed phrase,
it says that it is not valid.

When I checked the english.h file on github, the word "government" is no longer in the dictionary. It was replaced by "governing".
However, the word "government" still exists in english_old.h file,
but how to use the old word dictionary to restore wallet?

Replacing one word for another obviously does not generate a valid combination of seed phrase.

Therefore, in 2023, what is the procedure to restore moner that were created with older monero wallets?

Comment: The English (old) wordlist is still supported and should be detected fine.

https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/restore_account.html